# References created in bibliography, but not in text

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using apacite in my project to cite my sources.
I'm also using BibDesk.

I have my source in BibDesk. When I run in Latex, then Bibtex, then latex again, everything goes according to plan, except for the fact that my citation in my text still stays (?, ?). This is how I've cited it in my text:

```
\cite{ref:mas}
\cleardoublepage

% Bibliography section
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{./References/thesisref}
```

Console output when running BibTex:
[image]

Console output when running LaTeX again:
[image]

Some screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)? Please also show us the relevant entry in your .bib file

Comment: Ok I tried to figure out the MWEB and downloaded the filecontents package, but I have no clue what to do with it, even after having read the manual. I can't even explain what I'm doing when I have the filecontents package, because I have no idea what to do with it. I'm looking it up on Youtube now.

Comment: I think I know what I'm supposed to do. Working on the MWEB now. Can you paste code in a comment of a question?

Comment: I hope this helps?: 

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref:mas}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{./References/thesisref}

\end{document}


What is in my .bib file

@article{ref:mas,
 Author = {Aaker D. A.},
 Date-Added = {2018-12-30 2:33:11 PM +0100},
 Date-Modified = {2018-12-30 3:12:51 PM +0100},
 Journal = {California Management Review},
 Number = {2},
 Pages = {91-106},
 Title = {Managing Assets and Skills: The Key to a Sustainable Competitive Advantage},
 Volume = {31},
 Year = {1989}}

Comment: Retrying this with the right syntax: 
`\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\begin{document} 
\cite{ref:mas} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{./References/thesisref} 
\end{document}`
What is in my .bib file 

`@article{ref:mas, 
Author = {Aaker D. A.}, 
Date-Added = {2018-12-30 2:33:11 PM +0100}, 
Date-Modified = {2018-12-30 3:12:51 PM +0100}, 
Journal = {California Management Review}, 
Number = {2}, 
Pages = {91-106}, 
Title = {Managing Assets and Skills: The Key to a Sustainable Competitive Advantage}, 
Volume = {31}, 
Year = {1989}}`

Comment: `Author = {Aaker D. A.},` looks wrong and should probably be `Author = {Aaker, D. A.},`, but I doubt that is the source of the issue here. Note that your error message complains about curly braces. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and provide full example document. Please also include error messages and warnings as copyable text and not as images.

Comment: Ok, I'll provide the full example document soon. I've tried to do the exact same thing but I just changed the `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` to `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` (and of course got rid of the `\usepackage{apacite}`command) because there was a tutorial on YouTube where this worked. This also works for me. I get the [1] reference in my text, and the bibliography at the end is also completed. So I think there must be something wrong with the apacite way of citing sources in my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load apacite *after* hyperref:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite} 


\begin{document} 
\cite{ref:mas} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{test} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that did it! Thanks a lot. I'll have to change the way I implement the author's name as well because otherwise, it doesn't use the whole name in the text.

Comment: @StijnBotteldoorne Please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) this answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓) if it helped you. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ticked the checkmark and upvoted your solution (although I don't have 15 rep points yet). Thanks again!